# Extracting pattern from command output using sed with returns entire command instead of only matched substring

Tags: sed

I am trying to extract `aa49a30add59` from the following command but the `\1` back reference is not providing me the substring but the entire match with -e option.

```
bash$ docker images | grep '^aaa' | sed -e "s/aaa\s+xxx\s+\([0-9]+\)\s+/\1/"
aaa                                                     xxx                aa49a30add59        33 

bash$ docker images | grep '^aaa' | sed -e "s/\(?:aaa\s+xxx\s+\)\([0-9]+\)\s+/\1/"
aaa                                                     xxx                aa49a30add59        33 minutes ago      1.52 GB
```

Here only `aaa` and `xxx` is fixed, rest all is dynamic.

How to get only the matched subset here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following :

```
docker images | sed -nE "s/^aaa\s+xxx\s+([0-9a-f]+)\s*/\1/p"
```

- `-E` switches to the ERE regex flavour where unescaped brackets and `+` are parsed as metacharacters. Now your `+` work, but
- we now need to unescape the brackets.
- we need `[0-9a-f]` rather than `[0-9]` to match hexadecimal digits
- there may be no trailing space, so `\s*` instead of `\s+`
- adding the anchor, the `-n` and the final `p` makes the `sed` command perform the `grep` command's job, which can now be removed

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/tsJVhZ).

Comment: Works with slight modification - `docker images | sed -nE "s/^e2e\s+latest\s+([0-9a-f]+).*/\1/p"`